# Find the equation of a line with gradient -2/3 through the point (4,-6). Give your answer in the form ax+by+c=0 where a is a positive integer.

Tags: geometry

I am given the formula $$ax+by+c=0$$ the point $(4,-6)$ and the slope $-2/3$. I am asked to find $a$,$b$, and $c$. I have been trying to find results for a while. It says $a$ is a positive integer but that doesn't make sense to me since $m=- 2/3$.

I have never encountered a question like this and I have no idea how to tackle it...

Comment: hint: $m=-\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: You can always multiply both sides by $-1$ at the end to make $a$ positive.

Comment: Can you bring it to $ y=mx+c,\,$( slope ,- $y\,$ intercept) form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The searched equation has the form $$y=-\frac{2}{3}x+n$$ since we have given $$x=4,y=-6$$ we get for $n$:
$$n=-6+\frac{8}{3}=-\frac{10}{3}$$

Can you proceed?

The result should be $$2x+3y+10=0$$

Comment: sorry but I don't really get where you got the 2,3 and 10 from can you maybe add a few more steps, explain it like I am 5?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: General Equation of a [line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) with slope $m$ and passing through a point $(x_1,y_1)$ is:

$y-y_{1}=m(x-x_{1})$.

Put the values in the above equation and then rearrange in the form $ax+by+c=0$.

So with the above values, the equation becomes :

$y-(-6)=-\frac{2}{3}(x-4)$

$ \implies 3(y+6)=-2(x-4)$

$ \implies3y+18=-2x+8$

$\implies 3y+2x+10=0$

Comment: @MihaiMunteanu If you cannot understand this then you should brush up your equation solving skills as well as Geometry (at least for [Lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)))